# Weird stack trace in exception "The incoming request does not match any route"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-6, publish

i have published asp.net mvc application on iis 6 on the server(windows server 2003) from local machine. On server i have set the default page to default.aspx. but when i try to browse the site on server, it gives me exception
**"The incoming request does not match any route"**
One thing i noticed is that. Stack trace on line 5 is shown below. it has one weird thing that exception is still pointing to my local machine path

```
[HttpException (0x80004005): The incoming request does not match any route.]
   System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext) +15589
   System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext) +40
   System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingHandler.System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +7
   **UserManagement._Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\Evoletpublishnew\UserManagement\UserManagement\Default.aspx.cs:18**
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +50
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +627
```

Comment: 2 things. What routes do you have set up and what route are you trying to access?

Comment: please see the comment below i ve shown my maprroute. the above exception occur when i try to access http:\\localhost:8800 on server. if i access http:\\localhost:8800\account.mvc it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I changed the global.asax registerroutes as follows:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
routes.MapRoute( "Default", "{controller}.mvc/{action}/{id}",
      new { action = "Index", id = "" }
   );
routes.MapRoute( "Root", "",
      new { controller = "Account", action = "Index", id = "" }
   );
```

Answer (score 0):

All requests that aren't ignored need to map to some controller and action, which you are probably missing. Typically the default route looks like this and would be the last entry in your route table:

```
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
);
```

The reference you're seeing to your local machine is just the location of the file from which the assembly was compiled.

Comment: i think it is already there. Please take a look at my registerRoute


public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",                                              // Route name
                "{controller}.mvc/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "account", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
                
            );

Comment: What does your Default.aspx contain?

Comment: i haven't changed anything it is default as asp.net mvc generated